# How to connect multiple post in each other wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can some one help me on this? I want to make a page name gallery and in that page there are multiple post, in every post there are also multiple post connected to it. For example in gallery page there is post title Doomsday inside doomsday there are 10 or 20 post connected... can anyone give me some idea on it or reference. thanks.

Comment: You might want to try searching to see if anyone has made a WordPress plugin for something like this...

Comment: i see post 2 post and i create connection in function.php but how to connect a post to each other using the connection that i make

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right, you want a page that shows posts from a specific category(s).

To do this properly you need to make a custom page template, setup the divs and put this code in those divs:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=3&orderby=rand&numberposts=5');
foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see in the first line of code you can change the value of category, order and number of posts. Edit this to your requirement.

Use the same code in other divs to be able to put more post categories (and their corresponding posts) in the same page.

Comment: actually my first solution is use the post 2 post plugin that will connect my custom post in multiple post... i just read this answer and i just realize that i can view post that have same categories but the porblem is that i want to connect the multiple post by there title and having categories by title is a big mess bcoz this will produce many categories...

Comment: Well if you have posts in different categories and you have "categorized" them internally by their titles, and you want to mash them all up in one page, then you should use an additional category for those then use the said category to bring up these specific posts. For example you have [Topic 1 Category A], [Topic 1 Category B], [Topic 3 Category C]... you then add an additional, classifying category for the above 3 thus [Topic 1 Category A, Category Special], [Topic 1 Category B, Category Special], [Topic 3 Category C, Category Special].